# What will this 3rd arg of functions will do where function definition will be there in lua?

Tags: lua

I am looking for an explanation of the 3rd argument in uv.tcp_connect and uv.getaddrinfo. How to get the real function name or fun definition? At tcp_connect I saw this third argument as function(err).

1. `function(err)` -error is string
   At getaddress has 3rd argument.
2. `function(res,err)`
   Most of the places callback() or function () is calling.
3. `callback()` - how to determine this callback is going to call which API ? I know it's all are callback but in my lua code difficult to find fun definition.

Comment: your post doesn't make too much sense, please provide more context.  where did you find what you don't understand?

Comment: referring 3rd argument in lua API uv.getaddrinfo(host, service, [hints, [callback]]
callback is -( function (res,err) ) and uv.tcp_connect(tcp, host, port, callback) callback is -function(err)

Comment: just post a link to what you're referring to. you should learn how to convey information befor you do any programming. I made a guess what you want to know. please improve your post so people don't have to guess what you want to know. also realize that there are thousands of Lua APIs out there. it would help to know which one your talking about because Lua does not know anything about tcp

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess what you want to know.

> uv.tcp_connect(tcp, host, port, callback) callback is -function(err)

This line tells you that the function `uv.tcp_connect` has four parameters. `tcp`, `host`, `port` and `callback`.

`callback` is a function value with one parameter `err`.

So you would typically do something like this (assuming err is a str

```
local myCallback = function (err) print("The error is: " .. err) end
uv.tcp_connect(myTcp, myHost, myPort, myCallback)
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
uv.tcp_connect(myTcp, myHost, myPort, function (err) print("The error is: "..err) end)
```

At some point the program will call your callback and provide the arguments according to the parameter list.